# SQL query finding maximum for two joint tables by category

Tags: php, mysql

I'm wondering how to find the maximum of each category if I have to join two tables.

I have two tables. Restaurant which possesses a name, address, cuisine, county (area) and rid (restaurant id).

I also have an inspection which has an rid, idate (date of inspection) and totalscore (the inspection score for that restaurant).

Say I have to display a cuisine of a restaurant, name of a restaurant, its address and its totalscore (from an inspection class). I have to list the best restaurant for each cuisine in a particular county ('Cobb' in my code) and the date of the inspection must be in 2015. For instance, Chinese cuisine would be "Beijing Central" with a totalscore of 99 (out of 100).

So far I have this code:

```
    select distinct cuisine, name,address,
    max(totalscore) from restaurant r join inspection i on r.rid = i.rid
    where county = 'Cobb' and year(idate) = 2015 group by cuisine, name, 
    adddress;
```

While this gets me close, I keep getting duplicate copies. For instance, it lists two different chinese restaurants instead of choosing the best one.

I'm trying to improve my sql coding style so if anyone has a solution or best practices, it would be appreciated!

----EDIT---
Here is some of the sample data from my database when I do join inspection and restaurant on rid.

```
 rid | idate      | totalscore | name              | county | street              | cuisine  |
+-----+------------+------------+-------------------+--------+---------------------+----------+
|  13 | 2015-01-04 |         90 | Heirloom          | Cobb   | 2243 Akers Mill Rd  | American |
|  14 | 2015-01-27 |         49 | China Moon        | Cobb   | 2810 Paces Ferry Rd | Chinese  |
|  14 | 2015-02-27 |         83 | China Moon        | Cobb   | 2810 Paces Ferry Rd | Chinese  |
|  15 | 2015-03-27 |         77 | House of Chan     | Cobb   | 2469 Cobb Pkwy      | Chinese  |
|  16 | 2015-03-18 |         47 | I Love Sushi      | Cobb   | 2086 Cobb Pkwy      | Japanese |
|  16 | 2015-04-18 |         87 | I Love Sushi      | Cobb   | 2086 Cobb Pkwy      | Japanese |
|  17 | 2015-05-18 |         90 | Douceur de France | Cobb   | 277 S Marietta Pkwy | French   |
|  18 | 2015-05-22 |         59 | Swapna            | Cobb   | 2655 Cobb Pkwy      | Indian   |
|  18 | 2015-06-22 |         75 | Swapna            | Cobb   | 2655 Cobb Pkwy      | Indian   |
|  19 | 2015-06-18 |         32 | Mezza Luna        | Cobb   | 1669 Spring Rd      | Italian  |
|  19 | 2015-07-18 |         98 | Mezza Luna        | Cobb   | 1669 Spring Rd      | Italian  |
```

desired result will be something like

Indian: Swapna : 75
Chinese : China Moon : 83
Italian : Mezza Luna : 98 
...etc etc

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Okay. I went ahead and did that. Hopefully it clarifies things,

Comment: I create SQL Fiddle for you and add it in my previous answer. Check it it's seams to work but if there is any problem please tell us so we can improve query.. GL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it would be great if you can create an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).   If I understand you correctly you want to select max value for each group (cuisine). You should look [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) how to do that.

Here how your query could look like:

```
SELECT r.cuisine, r.name, r.address, i.totalscore 
FROM restaurant r 
JOIN inspection i 
ON r.rid = i.rid
WHERE county = 'Cobb' AND year(idate) = 2015
AND totalscore = (SELECT MAX(i1.totalscore)
                  FROM FROM restaurant r1
                  JOIN inspection i1
                  ON r1.rid = i1.rid
                  WHERE r.cuisine = r1.cuisine);
```

Hope that work, i couldn't test it because you didn't provide some data in your question...

GL!

**EDIT**
Hi from your edit in question I try to create two table you use in this query and test it, and my query forks fine... Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/420687/10) so you can check this scenario and add some data to it so we can tune up query if needed.

Comment: This gave the same output to my code. For some reason, some of the cuisines were not in the result. I'm going to try and put up some sample data points in my database. Maybe it will make more sense then.

Comment: @AkshayShukla any way one more thing I forgot to mention in answer is that there is no need to use both DISTINCT and GROUP BY on cuisine it's pretty much the same thing... and yes it would be great if you could provide sql fiddle with sample data so we can test our queries... GL

Comment: Okay I added in some of my data base to make things clearer for people. Hope it clarifies things!

Comment: @AkshayShukla hi again, there are two little problems at the moment, first you mark my answer as accepted (best answer) and I think your problem is still not solved so it's it's not very good because other member probably will pay a less attention  on your problem because they will think it's solved, so unmark it! And second think is that with added data things are clearer but also it would be even better if you provide your both table date (restaurant and inspection) separately with a some data so we can test it from scratch.